# Auto Sort with empty text cells at the bottom instead of the top

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I have a roster of names pulled from another sheet then auto sorted using macros.

When the formula returns no value "empty text" it is pushed to the top. How do I push it to the bottom while still returning the sorted value ascending?

```vb
Public Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Sheet6.Unprotect Password:="xxxxxxx"
     
    Range("A1:F151").Sort Key1:=Range("A1"), _
      Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
      OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
      Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
           
    Sheet6.Protect Password:="xxxxxxx", _
      DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
      
End Sub
```

Comment: Sort so empty cells are at the bottom, then change the range to avoid empty cells and resort to ascending.

Answer (score 0):

### Sort Ascending: Blanks to the Bottom

- Uncomment the `Debug.Print` lines to monitor the ranges at the four 'stages'.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Me.Unprotect Password:="xxxxxx"
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const Cols As String = "A:F"
    Const FirstRow As Long = 1
    Const CriteriaColumn As Long = 1
    
    ' Define Source Range (There are many ways).
    
    ' Define Processing Range (from defined first row to bottom-most row).
    With Columns(Cols).Resize(Rows.Count - FirstRow + 1).Offset(FirstRow - 1)
        ' Validate Criteria Column.
        If .Columns.Count < CriteriaColumn Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        ' Define Source First Cell Range ('fCell').
        Dim fCell As Range
        Set fCell = .Cells(1)
        'Debug.Print fCell.Address
        ' Define Source Range ('rng').
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = Intersect(fCell.CurrentRegion, .Cells)
        'Debug.Print rng.Address
    End With
    
    ' Sort Source Range.
    
    ' Sort descending.
    rng.Sort Key1:=fCell.Offset(, CriteriaColumn - 1), _
             Order1:=xlDescending, _
             Header:=xlYes
    ' Define Last Non-Blank Cell in Criteria Column ('lCell').
    Dim lCell As Range
    Set lCell = rng.Columns(CriteriaColumn).Find(What:="*", _
                                             LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                             SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    'Debug.Print lCell.Address
    ' Define Non-Blank Range ('rng').
    Set rng = rng.Resize(lCell.Row - rng.Row + 1)
    'Debug.Print rng.Address
    ' Sort Non-Blank Range ascending.
    rng.Sort Key1:=fCell.Offset(, CriteriaColumn - 1), _
             Order1:=xlAscending, _
             Header:=xlYes

    Me.Protect Password:="xxxxxx", _
      DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: I am new at this and this seems a little out of my skill set. Is there any chance you would be willing to simplify it for me. I tried a few attempts with what you sent with no luck. I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: If it doesn't work, then there is no use. This is an `Event Code` which when put in the right place, automatically does what was required. It should be copied into the sheet module of the worksheet where it should sort. For example, if the worksheet name is "Sheet1", then in VBE in the project explorer double-click on the sheet that has "Sheet1" in parentheses. Copy the code to the window that just opened. Now when you go to Excel, still nothing is happening. The code triggers only after another worksheet is selected, and you select "Sheet1". The code cannot be in `Module1` or `Thisworkbook`.

Comment: I was finally able to look at this upon my return to work. This worked wonderfully, exactly what I needed to do. You were a great help, I have been working on this for months. I greatly appreciate your expertise.